# How to avoid using "kill <PID>" command every time on getting the error: listen EADDRINUSE nodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm running a simple MERN stack application on my local server(macOS). Although I figured out how to kill the process using the below statement, I wonder if there is a way to prevent getting EADDRINUSE error often?

```
kill -9 <PID>
```

I've been getting this error very regularly and it's affecting my productivity to kill and restart the server many times. Any insights on it?

Using nodemon v1.18.9 to monitor changes and start the server.

Comment: This depends on your application. Consider providing https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and checking https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask